# How to find out addressHeader p2shHeader

Tags: bitcoin-core, p2sh

I am trying to find out the location or a method (may be) for addressHeader and p2shHeader parameter for any altcoin. The following list contains these 2 parameters for few coins but I am unable to find the source of these.

```
addressHeader = 30  Digital coin
addressHeader = 25; Blackcoin
addressHeader = 76; Dash
addressHeader = 30; Dogecoin
addressHeader = 0   Crown
addressHeader = 14; Feathercoin
addressHeader = 25; NuBits
addressHeader = 63; NuShares
addressHeader = 68; Uro
addressHeader = 30; Verge

p2shHeader = 5;     Digitalcoin
p2shHeader = 85;    Blackcoin
p2shHeader = 16;    Dash
p2shHeader = 22;    Dogecoin
p2shHeader = 5;     Crown
p2shHeader = 5;     Feathercoin
p2shHeader = 26;    NuBits
p2shHeader = 64;    NuShares
p2shHeader = 5;     Uro
p2shHeader = 33;    Verge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are address prefixes: A value prepended to a pubKey hash or scriptHash before base58 encoding. Assuming they are bitcoin forks and share similar source code, you can find them in the source code (eg. Dogecoin):

[chainparams.cpp Line #128](https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L128)

I haven't seen a list of altcoin address prefixes, but I can see how that might be useful.